# Can I loop over the keys of an associative array with the same syntax as bash and zsh

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I want to loop over the keys of an associative array, but I would like my script to work in zsh and bash. Would there be a way of doing it (syntax) that it would work in both

I know this

zsh:

```
for k in "${(k)array[@]}" do echo $k; done
```

bash:

```
for k in "${!array[@]}" do echo $k; done
```

Btw. I actually use oh-my-zsh, so I cannot really use something as `emulate ksh`, because it makes my terminal crash.

Comment: I would generally advise against trying to share code between zsh and bash -- they're quite deliberately incompatible in places (where bash is a superset of POSIX sh, whereas zsh abandons the standard where it codifies questionable decisions). The unquoted expansion in `echo $k` (vs `echo "$k"`) is an example of a subtler difference, but one that can [easily cause serious bugs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Comment: Is there a good reason not to use a hash-bang at the top of the script in order to choose a specific shell, regardless of what shell a user is running (e.g #!/bin/zsh)?

Comment: @UncleCarl, given the note about oh-my-zsh, I'm assuming that this is for code the OP wants to be able to source into an interactive shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap each implementation in a function, and define only the function appropriate to the current shell:

```
if [[ $ZSH_VERSION ]]; then
  keys_for_array() {
    local array=$1 dest=$2
    [[ $1 && $2 ]] || { echo "Usage: keys_for_array source-array dest-array" >&2; return 1; }
    : ${(AP)dest::=${(kP)array}}
  }
elif [[ $BASH_VERSION && ! $BASH_VERSION =~ ^([123][.]|4[.][012]) ]]; then
  keys_for_array() {
    [[ $1 && $2 ]] || { echo "Usage: keys_for_array source-array dest-array" >&2; return 1; }
    local -n array=$1 dest=$2
    eval 'dest=( "${!array[@]}" )'
  }
else
  keys_for_array() { echo "ERROR: keys_for_array not available for this shell" >&2; return 1; }
fi

[[ $ZSH_VERSION ]] && typeset -A aa=( 1 one 2 two )
[[ $BASH_VERSION ]] && declare -A aa=( [1]=one [2]=two )
keys_for_array aa aak

declare -p aak
```

...when run on bash, output is:

```
declare -a aak=([0]="1" [1]="2")
```

...when run on zsh, output is:

```
typeset -a aak=( 1 2 )
```

In either case, you can then iterate over them:

```
keys_for_array aa aak
for key in "${aak[@]}"; do
  echo "Key $key has value ${aa[$key]}"
done
```

---

Note that above, both functions are syntactically valid in both shells. Otherwise, it might be necessary to use `eval` or `source` to pull them in only conditionally. Personally, I would create two separate files with both bash and zsh versions of your portability library, and source only the file appropriate to the current shell.

Comment: `: ${(AP)dest::=${(kP)array}}` should let you do away with `eval`.

Comment: The invalid syntax isn't a problem until you try to *call* the function.

Comment: `zsh` chokes on the `bash` syntax if history expansion is enabled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176442/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-chepner).

Answer (score 0):

Not enough reputation points to comment on previous answer, but I can answer?

Don't forget to add a '!' to get the keys vs the values.

`keys_for_array aa aak
for key in "${!aak[@]}"; do
echo "Key $key has value ${aa[$key]}"
done`